# How to remove all the subnet in notepad++ something like below

Tags: notepad++

Input:

```
10.148.0.0/17 
10.126.0.0/23 
10.126.48.0/20
```

Want it to be like this:

```
10.148.0.0 
10.126.0.0
10.126.48.0
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you dealing with a long list of records? Are you trying to just remove the slash notation from the end of each octet? Please use the EDIT button to add more information to your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> in Notepad++ to bring up the find and replace window:

[image]

And then, in the top text box called find what: add `\/\d\d?`.

#### Don't forget to click in the search mode box regular expression

```
\/   # searches for the literal /
\d   # searches for any one digit
\d?  # searches for zero or one digit
```

Then leave the replace with blank and press the button 'Replace all'.

Comment: What will happen with the subnet `10.0.2.1/8`?

Comment: It'll find and remove it to as it searches for one or two digits after the /

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use `\/\d{1,2}` as the search target in "Find what:" textbox of find and replace window in Notepad++.